# What is a good automated data import method for SQL Server?

Tags: database, ms-access, sql-server-2008, import

I'm in the process of porting some SQL Server 2005 databases to SQL Server 2008. One of these databases has an associated import application (Windows task) which uses [SSIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Integration_Services) with a [DTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Transformation_Services) package to import a large dataset from an MS Access database nightly.

In upgrading to SQL Server 2008, I discovered that I can't run the same console application which has been performing the imports due to the missing manageddts DLL in SQL Server 2008. It's several years old and in need of a rewrite for various reason, plus, I've been fairly unhappy with DTS in general. The original reason DTS was chosen was for speed (5 min import time compared to 30+ for ADO.NET).

The format of the data to import is out of my control (the client likes Access). I would also like to be able to run the import from a machine completely separate from the server hosting SQL Server and preferably with minimal SQL features installed.

Options I've considered:

- Creating an Access application to connect to both databases (SQL Server and Access) and perform the import (Ugh!)
- Revisiting ADO.NET to see if the original implementation was poorly written.
- Updated SSIS packages.

What other technologies should I be considering for this job?

Comment: Why does using Access for his prompt an immediate rejection? It understands both sides of the equation. What's not to like?

Comment: VBA Sucks. I think I've found solution. I'll mention below.

Comment: @Joel: I think you need to stop and figure out why your 2005 solution doesn't work in 2008. A SQL Server 2005 SSIS solution should work in SQL Server 2008 with no problems at all. You may be looking for a solution to a problem that does not exist.

Comment: @John: The reason the old solution doesn't work is because the code which executes the dts package required the manageddts dll which is missing in sql 2008. I tried copying it from another box but there are too many dependencies. I'm sure sql 2008 will let you update the package, and it probably offers new libraries for executing ssis packages, but I've never been happy with the functionality, and I needed something more flexible anyway. I ended up spending about 8 hours trying to make the old solution work, and 2 hours rewriting it for bulk insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received a suggestion that I use ADO.NET to convert the .mdb file to a bunch of flat files, then use tsql's bulk insert statement to import the flat files. If it works, I'll mark this as the answer.

**EDIT:**

This worked really well. Far speedier than the old DTS. One down side is that the import user must have bulkadmin rights, and the schema of the flat files must precisely match the tables, but a little coding solved the latter, and a secure, dedicated user account answers the former.

I'm fairly happy with the result.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should try SSIS. If you don't know enough of it, you will learn a new thing.